# Create NSArray with float value in a range of -1.0 +1.0 from C Array in identical format

Tags: nsarray, floating-accuracy

Ok, maybe  I'm tired but have some trouble when try to passing "float value" from an C array style to NSarray across  NSNumber and obtain identical data. 
What I would like achieve is pass  this value in other class for plotting audio Waveform.

assuming:

```
   //needed range from -1.0 to 1.0
   monoFloatDataLeft[i] = (float)left / 32768.0;
   monoFloatDataRight[i] = (float)right / 32768.0;


   ArraySx = &monoFloatDataLeft[i];
   ArrayDx = &monoFloatDataRight[i]; 
   NSLog(@"right %f\n",ArrayDx);

   [self floatSx:*(ArraySx) floatDx:*(ArrayDx)];
```

Output: right -0.000061

Now in function...

```
  -(void)floatSx: (float)left floatDx: (float) right{

 NSLog (@"Left in function  %f\n", left);
 NSLog (@"right in function  %f\n", right);

 NSArray *cannelLeftArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:left], nil];
 NSLog (@"cannelLeftArray  %@\n", canaleSinistroArray);

 NSArray *channelRightArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:right], nil];
 NSLog (@"channelRightArray  %@\n", canaleDestroArray);
```

}

```
Output:
Left in function  -0.000061
right in function  -0.000153

cannelLeftArray("-0.0001525879")

channelRightArray("-6.103516e-05")
```

Ok, what i need is populate the array with the same float value style like left and right in function...

Hope enough clear.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So basically you just need some values within `[-1.0, +1.0]`?

Comment: Yes, like this: (Left in function  -0.000061)
(right in function  -0.000153). This value is in  C Array and i need passing this value to another class in the same format as example.